# Remove substring + split column in list of names in CSV

Tags: python, list, csv, split, substring

I have a CSV file with a list of names that I am trying to edit. There are multiple changes I am trying to make. When opened with the code below, the printed csv shows as follows:

```
with open ('wedding table cards.csv',newline='') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            print(row)


['Mr. and Mrs. Scott Summers']
['Ms. Lorna Dane']
['Mr. Hank McCoy and Ms. Ororo Munroe']
['Mr. Logan Wolverine']
['Mr. and Mrs. Warren Worthington']
['Ms. Anna Marie and Mr. Remy Lebeau']
```

Below are the actions I need help with. Not sure if I should be using Regex or other functions to solve these problems.

1. For strings that have "Mr. and Mrs." in them, split the string into
   two columns (comma separated) Ex: "Mr. and Mrs. Scott Summers" -->
   "Mr. and Mrs." , "Scott Summers"
2. For strings that have "Mr." or "Ms." in them, remove the title from
   the string ex: "Ms. Lorna Dane" --> "Lorna Dane"
3. For strings that have are structured as "Title. Name and Title Name"
   split string into two columns (comma separated) ex: "Mr. Hank McCoy
   and Ms. Ororo Munroe" --> "Mr Hank McCoy" , "Ms. Ororo Munroe"

For #1, here is what I have tried so far. It works except that it adds an extra space to the second column.

```
with open('wedding table cards.csv') as inf:
    with open('test_1.csv','w') as outf:
        for line in inf:
                outf.write('Mr. and Mrs.'.join(line.split('Mr. and Mrs.')))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way:

```
if 'Mr. and Mrs.' in line:
    line = 'Mr. and Mrs.,' + line[13:]
elif 'Mr.' in line or 'Ms.' in line:
    line = line[4:]
elif ' and ' in line:
    line = ','.join(line.split(' and '))
```

Comment: This worked! I'll have to test out a change to account for the second title in use case #3, but this gets me going in the right direction

`[Michael Feldstein and Ms. Alexandra Milstein]

[Benjamin Hochberger and Ms. Melissa Goldstein]`